# SQL Date Parameter Using 2 Date Columns for SSRS Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssms-2012

I have 3 columns,a reference number, a start date and an end date, These date columns are both in the dd/mm/yyyy format. I'd like to create a parameter in SSRS that allows the user to select a month (2016-07 for example) and it returns any dates that fall into that month. It's a bit difficult to explain but if I give the following example

REF NO 1 has a start date of 20/06/2016 and an end date of 15/07/2016, so if the user selected 2016-07 in the parameter it would return the result START DATE 01-06-2016 END DATE 15/07/2016. I hope I've explained this. This is the code so far, as you can see it's in its most basic form.

```
SELECT
 REF_NO
,START_DATE
,END_DATE
FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

A little unsure of the question, but:

Are the dates dynamic or are they always a set range?

```
Example:  
07/2016 = 01/06/2016 to 15/07/2016 
08/2016 = 01/07/2016 to 15/08/2016 
09/2016 = 01/08/2016 to 15/09/2016
```

You can set available values to a parameter in report builder. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283107.aspx

So you would set an available value labelled 07/2016 that would use the value 01/06/2016 - 15/07/2016